# Pass arguments to JsonDeserializer not via Annotations

Tags: java, jackson

I've the following requirement:
Write a `JsonDeserializer` that is invoked when doing something like:

```
public CustomConfiguration deserialize(User user, String data) {
    objectMapper.readValue(data, CustomConfiguration.class);
}
```

*AND* I would like to pass the `user` instance to the `deserialize` method.

P.S: I'm using SpringBoot 2.7.3, so my CustomDeserializes class uses the `@JsonComponent` annotation, so I'm able to `@Autowired` objects.

Is there a nice way to make this happen?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is by injecting the parameter using the ObjectMapper + @JsonInject annotation. Hope this helps anyone..

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson_annotations/jackson_annotations_jacksoninject.html